# Unable to access PageSpeed console installed alongside WordPress; getting 503 error and 'LimitInternalRecursion' error

Tags: centos, centos6, wordpress, apache-2.4, mod-pagespeed

On a CentOS 6 web server with Wordpress installed in /var/www/html/wordpress, and using PageSpeed for caching, I cannot access the /pagespeed_console through the web browser.

I only get a 503 error.

Searching through the httpd /var/log/httpd/error_log shows, "LimitInternalRecursion".

/var/log/httpd/access_log:

```
"GET /pagespeed_console HTTP/1.1" 500 395 "-" 
"Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_1)
 AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/32.0.1700.107 Safari/537.36"
```

/var/log/httpd/error_log:

```
Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable 
configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit 
if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace.
```

Comment: You didn't provide [nearly enough information](http://meta.serverfault.com/q/3608/126632) for us to help you. Some obvious things that are missing from the question are: the error message (it's not nearly long enough to justify linking to pastebin); your Apache virtual host configuration and .htaccess file; perhaps a description of exactly what you installed and how.

Comment: You should follow the instructions *in the error log* (**`Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace.`**) and debug your broken redirect - Or if you want us to help you do that at least *show us the broken redirect* from your configuration file...

Comment: Here is the debug output for the rewrite log: http://pastebin.com/GtRDieSM and the www.conf: http://pastebin.com/75P5FF27.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with SELinux for CentOS.

Type the following on the CLI: 
    chcon -R -t httpd_sys_content_t /var/cache/mod_pagespeed

Instructions are listed in the section "Why do I get Permission denied errors in my log file on CentOS, RHEL, or any system using SELinux?" at https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/module/faq

Answer (score 0):

your rewrite rule is colliding and generating an internal redirect massacre.

just add another condition to it so that /pagespeed_console is not rewritten.

```
 <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteBase /
        RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
        RewriteRule ^server-status$ - [L]
        # do not parse mod_pagespeed URIs
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/mod_pagespeed_[a-z_]+$
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
        RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
    </IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

This helps me, in pagespeed.conf:

```
.....
<Location /pagespeed_admin>
        <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
            RewriteEngine Off
        </IfModule>
.....
```